# ProGuard not running from Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm running Eclipse Indigo with Android ADT 16. My project is at Android 2.2 (API 8). I've added a `proguard.cfg` file to the project root directory and added the following line to both `default.properties` and `project.properties`:

`proguard.config=proguard.cfg`

When I use the Eclipse Export wizard, a .apk file is generated, but it appears to be the same size as before I enabled ProGuard, and moreover there is no `proguard/` subdirectory in my project root directory. So it appears that ProGuard is not running. What other steps are necessary to enable ProGuard from Eclipse?

Thanks
Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proguard now requires Ant version 1.8+ to run properly, per this [post](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/19b96902fc20cede/30d99d79d3ba3f58?lnk=gst&q=proguard%20not%20running%20eclipse%20proguard.config#30d99d79d3ba3f58). My MacBook Pro comes with Ant version 1.7 - updating to Ant version 1.8.2 did the trick.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried exporting a signed apk package?  Proguard only runs when creating a release build.

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

> ProGuard is integrated into the Android build system, so you do not
>   have to invoke it manually. ProGuard runs only when you build your
>   application in release mode, so you do not have to deal with
>   obfuscated code when you build your application in debug mode. Having
>   ProGuard run is completely optional, but highly recommended.

Comment: I've generated the apk via Eclipse through the Export wizard, as well as Android Tools -> Export Signed Application Package (I assume those two pathways generate the same thing, right?) In either case, the proguard directory is NOT generated.

Comment: I just tried this with my app and it also did not generate a `proguard` directory, even with adding those flags to my `proguard.cfg`.  I used [dex2jar](http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/) on my signed APK and [JD-GUI decompiler](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui) on it and found that my class files did go through proguard though.  Weird that the `proguard` directory isn't getting generated...

Comment: Thanks @triad - is this strange Eclipse behavior (no proguard directory) new with Indigo, or have you seen it work with Indigo in the past?

Comment: Does the fact that my project uses Android 2.2 (android-8) matter?

Comment: I also note that proguard is not "silently" running in my case - the apk file size is unchanged from when my properties did not specify proguard. A google search seems to indicate that no one else has this problem, so it is very frustrating...

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe try creating a new Android project and adding `proguard.config=proguard.cfg` to your `project.properties` and seeing if even that works.  If that does work, then at least you know there's something not configured right in your original project.  If that still doesn't work, maybe a fresh reinstall of Eclipse might help.

Comment: I tried creating a new Android project in Eclipse at SDK level 2.2 - a default proguard.cfg file is created. I add proguard.config=proguard.cfg to project.properties (there is no default.properties!), and run the Export wizard - however still no proguard/ directory created. As to re-installing Ecipse, I just installed the latest 3 days ago, which took several hours to download - yikes...